# Division with remainder in $K[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field and $f\in K[x,y]$ such that $a:=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)\not=0$. Let $b:=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$. In a lecture of mine, it was claimed now that we can divide $f$ by $ax+by\in K[x,y]$ to obtain a representation
$$f(x,y)=e(x,y)(ax+by)+h(y)$$
where $e\in K[x,y]$ and $h\in K[y]$. Why is this the case?

I tried to consider $f\in K[x,y]\subset K(y)[x]$ where $K(y)$ denotes the field of rational functions in $y$. Then there is an "ordinary" division with remainder yielding
$$f(x,y)=\tilde e(x,y)(ax+by)+\tilde h(y)$$
where $h\in K(y)$ (as the $x$-degree has to be strictly less than $1$) and $\tilde e\in K(y)[x]$. Is there a way to conclude the desired representation from that or is there some deeper theory behind?
I apologize in advance if some notation is incorrect; unfortunately, it's not my specialization: I am not an algebraist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to go to $K(y)$ for your division. Let $R$ be any commutative ring with 1, $p(x)\in R[x]$ be a polynomial with leading term a unit in $R$ and $\deg p(x)=d$. Then, given any $f(x)\in R[x]$, you can divide to get $f(x)=q(x)p(x)+r(x)$ and $\deg r(x)<d$. In your case, take $R=k[y]$, $p(x)=ax+by$.